# Не срабатывает вызов диалога открытия файла Python PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Не срабатывает вызов диалога открытия файла Python PyQT5. Выдает ошибку типа аргумента argument 1 has unexpected type.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Ui_MainWindow(QAction, object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 541))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 551))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuConvert = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuConvert.setObjectName("menuConvert")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts.setObjectName("actionConvert_Nokia_contacts")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menuConvert.addAction(self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuConvert.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        #Привязка действий к кпунктам меню
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.OpenFile)
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts.triggered.connect(self.Convert)
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.Exit)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Converter"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuConvert.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Convert"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Convert Nokia contacts"))

    def OpenFile(self):
        #Вот эта строка генерит ошибку
        op = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home')[0]
        return(op)

    def Exit(self):
        import sys
        sys.exit()

    def Convert (self, OpenFile):
        try :
            global op
            global fpath
            f=str(op)
            import readfile
            readfile.workNokia(f)
            print('Process')
        except (NameError):
            self.OpenFile()
```

Comment: Так у вас `self` - это `QAction`, а первым аргументом ожидается тип, приводимый к `QWidget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже отписал  [@mkkik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788832/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-python-pyqt5/788846#comment1241650_788832)  у вас была проблема со строчкой `QAction`
Было
`class Ui_MainWindow(QAction, object)`
Стало
`class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow, object)`

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow, object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 541))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 551))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuConvert = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuConvert.setObjectName("menuConvert")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts.setObjectName("actionConvert_Nokia_contacts")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menuConvert.addAction(self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuConvert.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        #Привязка действий к кпунктам меню
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.OpenFile)
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts.triggered.connect(self.Convert)
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.Exit)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Converter"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuConvert.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Convert"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Convert Nokia contacts"))

    def OpenFile(self):
        op = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '')[0]
        return(op)

    def Exit(self):
        import sys
        sys.exit()

    def Convert (self, OpenFile):
        try :
            global op
            global fpath
            f=str(op)
            import readfile
            readfile.workNokia(f)
            print('Process')
        except (NameError):
            self.OpenFile()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Если не сложно, подскажите где был косяк, не нахожу. У меня был запуск сторонним модулем. Тут вы запуск виджета в конец добавили

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеев обновил ответ